# Got a blank page when sending email using $mail = JFactory::getMailer();

Tags: php, joomla

I am getting blank page when sending email to user in joomla. 
I can also get error "Class 'JMail' not found".
Is there any help ?

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: I have put it but no effect, still its blank page.

Comment: Here I am pasting code for library of joomla.
public static function sendMail($from, $fromname, $recipient, $subject, $body, $mode = 0, $cc = null, $bcc = null, $attachment = null,
  $replyto = null, $replytoname = null)
 {
  // Deprecation warning.
  JLog::add('JUtility::sendmail() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

  // Get a JMail instance
  $mail = JFactory::getMailer();

  return $mail->sendMail($from, $fromname, $recipient, $subject, $body, $mode, $cc, $bcc, $attachment, $replyto, $replytoname);
 }

Comment: In this I can debug still before $mail = JFactory::getMailer(); but it stops to send mail.

Comment: @NileshKhatri please add code editing original question (“edit” before tag list), not in comment. Your code is not understandable in the comment, especially because it has comments, and without linebreaks we can't know what is commented, what not.

Comment: You will get Joomla specific answer from the Joomla Q&A Stack Exchange site…http://joomla.stackexchange.com

Comment: Its resolved . I have copied joomla folder from library to existing library.

Answer (score 0):

Its resolved . I have copied joomla folder from library to existing library.